# MySQL and PHP are fine but webservice is slow

Tags: php, mysql, rest, web-services, nginx

so I have a REST Webservice with a lot of users (~50k) and a lot of online, recently I faced a problem and cant fix it, 
web service has become really slow!

when I check with postman 1 request takes 1-4 sec!!
I checked MySQL with digesting slow-log and it was working fine (all requests were done in like 100ms or less)
I also checked PHP with:

```
$time = microtime(TRUE);
$mem = memory_get_usage();
//code here
print_r(array(
  'memory' => (memory_get_usage() - $mem) / (1024 * 1024),
  'seconds' => microtime(TRUE) - $time
));
```

and it was really fast, so in my eyes PHP and DB are fine but Webservice as a whole has become really slow!
don't know how to identify and fix the problem

NOTES:

6GB ram (MySQL taking half as I set it and ~ other half is buff/catch)

6 cores (MySQL user ~100-150% = 1-1.5 cores)

HDD is not full :)

CENTOS 7 - nginx - PLESK - php 7

Comment: One query can be fast, but your web service may do many queries per request. Also, maybe you got too many incoming requests, and the server just queues them and only processes so many at the same time.

Comment: You can check your server response time too.

Comment: @GolezTrol I checked with a simple code, even with no DB connection, it was still slow, about queuing I think it's possible but don't know how to check and confirm, also there could b some kind of attack maybe? I don't know I'm just inexperienced for this, how to check, confirm and fix?

Comment: @DiegoRosales how? :)

Comment: It is worth checking the configs of mysql and Apache for a max-connect

Comment: Please describe your server setup. Is it apache or nginx? Linux? What version? How is it handling php? fast-cgi, or what? How many webserver requests per second are you handling in your peak hour? How many do you need to handle? Is your web server accepting port 443 connections (https)? Does your server machine do anything besides handle these requests? Are you sharing the server with some other application? Is it a physical machine or a virtual machine?  (Your favorite nephew should not be running a Minecraft server on there, of course.)

Comment: @O.Jones nginx, centos7, I need like min 500 requests /sec I guess, it has https but I don't use it yet, and it's dedicated

Comment: I've not used this, but looks like good tips to monitor nginx https://blog.serverdensity.com/monitor-nginx/

Comment: I used a tool (from Apache, not nginx) call apache benchmark (ab). It would do a lot of test calls and break down the results between different components. might want to look at it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html

Comment: ab is indeed nice for testing individual calls. However, it didn't seem to trigger concurrent requests even though I specified it. At some point, I could break my web service by holding F5 in Chrome, but not using Apache ab. I ended up writing my own tool to really generate the load I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A sustained load of 500 requests per second is no light load. If none, or a very few, of those requests are timing out, you probably have tuned your web server configuration adequately. Why? When a Linux-based web server issues a [listen(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) request it sets up a couple of queues for incoming requests. Those requests wait until some worker in the server gets around to using [`accept(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) in order to start responding to them.

The 1.4 second time to respond probably is mostly spent in one of the listen queues.

You can try tuning nginix for a heavy load. You may be able to get more performance from it by adjusting things like the number of connections it accepts.

You should examine the code run by your web service to see if it contains anything unecessary. Does it read any files from the file system?  Your objective is this: once your php code starts processing a request, it should be able to finish it using as few shared resources (MySQL queries, file reads, etc) as possible.  If the php instances processing requests have to wait for each other a lot, your system will slow down.

Does your php-to-MySQL connection scheme use a connection pool. Make sure you use it. `mysqli_` and `PDO` both offer connection pools, but there are things you can do (even by mistake) to defeat connection pooling.

Many people in such a situation would *scale out* the server configuration, by adding more web server machines. You can use round-robin DNS, or you can learn about nginx's load balancing capabilities.